# Determine the "lang" attribute of <html> .on('change') and display items accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I have a site that uses a language translator plugin on Wordpress.  On this site, I have an image of a "certification badge" that has English on the image, but I also have a version that is in Spanish instead.  I am trying to force the English version to hide, and the Spanish version to show upon change of the HTML attribute 'lang' and have gotten most of the work completed and working, only it is working backwards.  It all starts out fine, but when I change the site language to Spanish, the badges don't change.  Then when I change back to English, the badges change to the Spanish version...  What am I missing?  The first block of code is for when the page initially loads, and the second is looking for the change event from the plugin.

```
//  Change PPE Badges based on language

if (jQuery("html").attr("lang").toLowerCase() === 'es' || jQuery("html").attr("lang").toLowerCase() === 'es-mx') {
    jQuery('.badgeSpanish').show();
    jQuery('.badgeEnglish').hide();
    console.log('Language: Spanish');
} else {
    jQuery('.badgeSpanish').hide();
    console.log('Language: English');
}

jQuery(document).on('change', 'html', function() {
    if (jQuery("html").attr("lang").toLowerCase() === 'es' || jQuery("html").attr("lang").toLowerCase() === 'es-mx') {
        console.log('Language: Spanish');
        jQuery('.badgeSpanish').show();
        jQuery('.badgeEnglish').hide();
    } else if (jQuery("html").attr("lang").toLowerCase() === 'en' || jQuery("html").attr("lang").toLowerCase() === 'en-us' || jQuery("html").attr("lang").toLowerCase() === 'auto') {
        console.log('Language: English');
        jQuery('.badgeEnglish').show();
        jQuery('.badgeSpanish').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the example site to demonstrate: http://harsini.staging.wpengine.com/

Comment: Maybe your jQuery is kicking in when the dropdown value changes but before the `<html>` tag's `lang` attribute has been updated?

Comment: How would I check for that, and fix it if it were the case?

Comment: Does the `doGTranslate()` function change the `lang` attribute? Since the dropdown already has a hardcoded `onchange`, just add your code there. So your hardcoded `onchange` handler would do this: `doGTranslate(this); doChangeIcons();`. Then just move your existing icon-swapping code into a function called `doChangeIcons()`.

Comment: That is not a bad idea.  I am not very proficient in php, so I will have to look into how exactly to do that, but i get what you are saying.  I am going to dig into this as a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot instead:

```
function updateBadge(){ 
    // gets rid of the need to constantly retrieve and mutilate the language
    var language = jQuery("html").attr("lang").toLowerCase();
    // a switch becomes useful because you can check against multiple values
    // and set a default if need be
    switch(language){
        case "es":
        case "es-mx":
            jQuery(".badgeEnglish").hide();
            jQuery(".badgeSpanish").show();
            break;
        default: 
            jQuery(".badgeSpanish").hide();
            jQuery(".badgeEnglish").show();
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // update the badge as soon as the document is ready
    updateBadge();
    // and update it every time the language is changed
    jQuery(this).on("change", "html", updateBadge);
});
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours, and the exact same thing is happening.  Nothing changes if I switch to Spanish, and then it swaps to the wrong language when I try to switch it back.